# Disqus Comments should be Formatted in Chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

In [room-15](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) on SO, we have recently started a [blog](http://room-15.github.io/blog/). We used Disqus to power comments, however, when we try to post them in the chat room, they aren't formatted the way comments on this site do. Not only us, but most site out there uses Disqus as well. Is it possible to add Disqus comment formatting to chat rooms, so we can see the comments live without having to click on the link? Thank you.

Comment: also it would be great if the comments themselves start working. currently then are read only — impossible to login and because of that impossible to add a comment.